# ckEditor ckfinder react image uploaded in the serve but its shown on editor for second the disapear with alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckfinder

look   guys i was facing this problem for 3 days now i need help on the ckeditor upload images im using ckfulleditor so all the plugins will be installed automaticly but  image upload this alert fired the photo dissapear even though its saved on the server

```
   import React, { useState } from "react";
      import CKFullEditor from 'rc-ckfulleditor'
      import "../../App.css";
      import { ip } from "../../root"



      export default function TextEditor(props) {
        const [text, setText] = useState("");


        const imagePluginFactory = (editor) => {
          editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
            console.log(loader)
          }
        }

        return (
          <div style={{ margin: props.margin && "0 0 0 1rem " }}>
            <h2>{props.editorName} :</h2>
            <CKFullEditor

              data={props.data}
              disabled={props.disabled}
              onChange={(event, editor) => {
                const data = editor.getData();
                setText(data);
                props.index !== undefined
                  ? props.pickNestedData(data, props.nameOnState, props.index)
                  : props.pickData(data, props.nameOnState);
              }}
              config={{

                ckfinder: {
                  uploadUrl: `${ip}api/offer/addPhotoForTest`
                }
              }}

            />

          </div >
        );
      }
```

[image: this is the image]

Comment: Are there any error messages in the dev console?

Comment: POST http://192.168.1.14:4000/api/offer/addPhotoForTest 500 (Internal Server Error)
when im using ckfinder i get this error but when i use costumupload the request is sended and the image is saved on the server